# Build product with ant4eclipse for windows on a linux machine

Tags: build, cross-platform, ant4eclipse

We're trying to build an RCP application with ant4eclipse. Our build server runs a Red Hat Linux. The building itself appears to be working, but the result is an application/x-executable for linux. Curiously I couldn't get it to run on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop either, but I thought that might be an incompatability with the distro.
Either way, the build seems to build the product for the platform the build script is run on, but we want a .exe file for windows.
Within the script we have the following properties:

```
<ant4eclipse:platformConfiguration id="win32.win32.x86"
                                                 windowingSystem="win32"
                                                 operatingSystem="win32"
                                                 architecture="x86" />
```

When building the product we use the following parameters:

```
<buildProduct 
            workspaceDirectory="${workspaceDirectory}"
            productfile="${productFile}" 
            targetPlatformId="target.platform" 
            destination="${targetDirectory}" 
            clearDestination="true" 
            os="win32" 
            debug="true"/>
```

Is anything missing to tell ant4eclipse to build for windows, or could some parameter be wrong in any way here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually quite easy. Weirdly enough te buildProduct makro didn't seem to recognize the setting where I set the platformConfigurationId. I checked the ant4eclipse macro file and saw, that the buildProduct macro also accepts a "platformConfigurationId" argument, which defaulted to an empty string - so the platform the product is being built on.
By passing

```
platformConfigurationId="win32.win32.x86"
```

to buildProduct I managed to get a product suited for Windows.